# Reload the content of a page several times with jQuery Ajax request to the node JS server

Tags: jquery

I'm programming a ServicePortal page for SAP as part of an internship, and I have a problem where I get stuck: It is a page with the ServiceCalls, i.e. tickets that have already been created, where the name of the contact person for the ticket is displayed in a separate column shall be.
[ServiceCalls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y4vz.jpg)
The data in the columns on this page are filled via a request from the NodeJS WebServer to the SAP ServiceLayer API, i.e. data is returned to a function in the NodeJS Server using JASON from the API, then parsed into an array of objects, and then corresponding properties of objects are displayed the HTML page.

```js
function listServiceCalls(inRes, inCustomerCode, inFrom){
log(`${serviceid}/ServiceCalls?$filter=CustomerCode eq '${inCustomerCode}'&skip=${inFrom}`);//Ausgabe in der Console

    request(
        {
            method: 'GET'
            , uri: `${serviceid}/ServiceCalls?$filter=CustomerCode eq '${inCustomerCode}'&$skip=${inFrom}&$top=20&$orderby=ServiceCallID desc`//Absteigend sortiert nach ServiceCallID alle ServiceCalls für Kundennummer mit der man eingeloggt ist ausgeben
            , headers: {
                Cookie: ` B1SESSION=${sessionid};`
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (response.statusCode === 401) {
                console.warn('Fehler: error = ' + error + ' response = ' + response.statusCode + ' body = ' + body);//Von hier
                console.warn('error = "{}"; response = "{}"; body = "{}"', error, response.statusCode, body);//
                loginSAP();
            } else if (response.statusCode >= 300) {
                console.error('error = ' + error + ' response = ' + response.statusCode + ' body = ' + body);
                inRes.writeHead(response.statusCode, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                inRes.end(body);}
             else {
                let calls = JSON.parse(body).value;
                let templatePage = fs.readFileSync("page/ListServiceCalls.html", "utf8");
                templatePage = templatePage.replace(/<<CustomerCode>>/g, inCustomerCode);
                let start = templatePage.indexOf('<!--ServiceCallStart-->') + '<!--ServiceCallStart-->'.length;
                let stop = templatePage.indexOf('<!--ServiceCallStop-->');
                let templateRow = templatePage.substring(start, stop);
                let page = "";
                let lines = "";
                if (calls) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
                        let obj = calls[i];
                        console.log(obj);
                        addStatusTextToCallObj(obj);
                        let template = '\`' + templateRow + '\n\t\`';
                        let line = '';
                        let code = 'line = ' + template;
                        eval(code);
                        lines = lines + line;

                    }
                    page = templatePage.substring(0, start) + lines + templatePage.substring(stop);
                }
                inRes.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                inRes.end(page);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In the returned object from ServiceCalls, however, there is no property "Contact Person", which I simply e.g. via $ {obj.ContactPerson} on the HTML page, but there is "ContactCode" that is the ID of the contact person, so a detour is necessary: ​​when the page is loaded I make a second request with ... jQuery to the function "aspSelect1", whereby in jQuery the ContactCode is passed to the function "aspSelect1", in the function "aspSelect1" a request is made to "ContactEmployees" in the API, because the returned object contains all the names of the contact persons of the relevant customers and IDs (ContactCode), so you can use the ID to calculate the contact person

```js
function aspSelect1(inRes, inCustomerCode, inContactCode) {
    request(
        {
            method: 'GET'
            , uri: `${serviceid}/BusinessPartners?$select=ContactEmployees&$filter=CardCode eq '${inCustomerCode}'`
            , headers: {
                Cookie: ` B1SESSION=${sessionid};`
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log('Fehler: ' + error + ' ' + body);
            let contacts= JSON.parse(body).value;
            let templatePage = fs.readFileSync("page/AspSelectOptions1.html", "utf8");
            templatePage = templatePage.replace('<<CustomerCode>>', inCustomerCode);
            let start = templatePage.indexOf('<!--AspPartnerStart-->') + '<!--AspPartnerStart-->'.length;
            let stop = templatePage.indexOf('<!--AspPartnerStop-->');
            let templateRow = templatePage.substring(start, stop);
            let page = "";
            let lines = "";
            //console.log('Contacts Länge: ', contacts.length);
            //console.log('Das ist ein Test');
            if (contacts) {
                for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                    let obj = contacts[i];
                    //console.log('ContaktEmployees: ', obj.ContactEmployees);
                    let obj1=obj.ContactEmployees;
                    for (let i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++){
                        if(obj1[i].InternalCode=== inContactCode) {
                            let obj2=obj1[i];
                            let template = '\`' + templateRow + '\n\t\`';
                            let line = '';
                            let code = 'line = ' + template;
                            eval(code);
                            lines = lines + line;
                        }
                    }

                }
                page = templatePage.substring(0, start) + lines + templatePage.substring(stop);
            }
            inRes.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            inRes.end(page);
        }
    );
}
```

```html
 $(document).ready(() => {
            let ContactCode = $('td#asp').html();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/aspSelect1',
            data: `&ContactCode=${ContactCode}`,
                cache: false,
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: (data) => {
                let selectColumn = $('#asp');
                selectColumn.empty().append(data);//der Ihnalt wird zuerst geleert und dann mit Data gefüllt
                },
            error: () => {}
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="logo" src="jpg/osc2.png" style="max-width: 40%" alt="">
<h1>Your ServiceCalls</h1>
<table>
    <tr><th class="size0">id</th><th class="size3">Subject</th><th>ContactPerson</th><th class="size1">Status</th><th class="size0">Action</th></tr>
    <!--ServiceCallStart--><tr><td class="num">${obj.ServiceCallID}</td><td class="subject">${obj.Subject}</td><!--AspPartnerStart--><td id="asp" name="asp"  >${obj.ContactCode}</td><!--AspPartnerStop--><td class="status">${obj.StatusText}</td><td><button onclick="formUpdateServiceCall('${obj.ServiceCallID}', '${obj.CustomerCode}');">Edit</button></td></tr><!--ServiceCallStop-->
    <tr><td colspan="4"><button style="float: left;"  onclick="prev();" >prev</button><button style="float: left;" onclick="next();" >next</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><button style="width:202%"  onclick="findServiceCall();" >Find ServiceCall</button></td>
        <td align=right><label for="servicecallid" ></label><input class="right" style="width: 65%;"  id="servicecallid" type="number" placeholder="Enter the ServiceID you are looking for here" /></td><td ><button style="width: 100%" onclick="enterServiceCall();" >NEW CALL</button></td>
        <td><button style="width: 100%" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://10.10.240.34:2222/login';" >LOGOUT</button></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

- I did that, only it is only done for the first line on the HTML page:[ServiceCalls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhNCC.jpg), because the jQuery request is only executed once when the page is loaded. How can you ensure that the jQuery request is executed every time the relevant   element is loaded, so that the column is filled with contact persons accordingly?